# Angular 1.2 form with several controllers

Tags: angularjs

There is Angular 1.2 form with several html input elements and single “Submit” button.

Most of elements on the form are handled by primary controller, 
but there are few elements which are managed by the second controller.
When user clicks "Submit" button both controllers are invoked independently (order is not forced) and they do modification in 2 different database tables.

The new business logic requires what when the elements which managed by the second controller  are modified then the primary controller should know about it and apply some logic.

So I think of 2 options:

1) controllers shall be invoked in specific order (how to do it?)

2) 2nd controller shall be eliminated completely; all logic shall be in single controller for entire form

What is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the second controller, since it handles the logic of just a few elements I see no reason to keep it.

(This is **probably** the best solution, however it might be not. If you provide the code for your problem we can actually be sure of what the best solution is)